# Return Multiple Columns from Different Tables

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables (`table1` and `table2`), each with 2 columns (`code` and `name`). I am able to identify the records in `table1` where the `name` is different for the same `code` in `table2`, but I can't seem to get both `name` columns to appear.

Here's where I'm at....

```
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT * FROM table2 
    WHERE table2.code = table1.code 
    AND table2.name = table1.name)
```

The results include only `table1.code` and `table1.name`, where I'd also like to include `table2.name`.

I'd appreciate any help on this!

Thanks!

Comment: You need to learn about [join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)).

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using (please update tags accordingly)....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT table1.code, table1.name, table2.name
FROM table1
inner join table2
on table2.code = table1.code
and table2.name != table1.name
```

Comment: Thanks, Sunny for the quick response, but Brian's response worked better.  In fairness to you, I did not state that both tables had the same number of records.

Sunny's code pulls back everything including items in table1 that aren't in table2, whereas Brian's code forced the CODE field in each table to match then checked for NAME being different.

Thanks to both for helping so quickly!